# arm-eabi-gcc: Internal error: Segmentation fault (program cc1)

Tags: android, build

I am building new Android system on Ubuntu 10.4 64-bit. While building, I got this error:

```
arm-eabi-gcc: Internal error: Segmentation fault (program cc1)
```

This command caused the error:

```
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -mthumb-interwork -Ibionic/libc/private -o out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -c bionic/libc/arch-arm/bionic/crtbegin_dynamic.S
```

It seems gcc has some errors. I've never seen gcc segfault before.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the arm compiler from?

Comment: Sorry, should be arm-eabi-4.3.1/bin/...

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is the issue of toolchain itself, the new one is not stable. After I  switch to older version, the issue is gone.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do a switch to older version?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android build, execute the below command, but before executing you should have sudo permissions.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs \
  x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit. I had plenty of space on all partitions.

It disappeared after I upgraded to **Ubuntu 10.10** 32-bit.